# Centre of Mass of a Constant Density Lamina

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble calculating the centre of mass of a constant density lamina. The problem is as follows:  Consider a constant density lamina (two–dimensional plate) with edges given by the curves y = x^(1/2) and y = −x + 2x^2. Calculate the centre of mass of the lamina.

I understand that I need to set up integrals to first find the mass - however I am confused if the mass should include the region below the x axis bound by y = -x + 2x^2 or not.

I have calculated the mass to equal 1/2*c (where c is the constant density) by integrating a double integral of constant c with bounds x=0 and x=1 and y = 2x^2 - x and y = x^(1/2) dy dx (apologies - I don't know how to write an integral on here).

Am I going about this the right way? If not, what is the correct method for calculating the centre of mass. I have searched the internet for hours for a similar problem which involves a region below the x-axis.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially correct. The center of mass is defined as follows

$$\mathbf{C}=\frac{\int \mathbf{r}dA}{\int dA}=\hat{\mathbf{i}} \frac{\int xdA}{\int dA} + \hat{\mathbf{j}} \frac{\int ydA}{\int dA}$$

You already have $A=1/2$ (assuming unit density), so just be careful with the double integrals. And yes, the area below the $x$-axis is part of the area being considered. You have the correct integration limits, as well.

Just for the record, I determined that $\mathbf{C}=(7/15,11/30)$ This was verified by numerical simulation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, happy to help. Gave me a chance to think about something I hadn't considered in a little while.